# Elasticsearch Single Node Reliability

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-elasticsearch

I'm thinking to use AWS' canned Elasticsearch service as a single node cluster to allow searching across a record set of 100MM small records (people's names and their company etc, as well as other attributes). Very read heavy, updates once every three months.

https://aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/

I want to use just one node to save on Amazon costs.

I will continue to master my data in AWS RDS, so this is where I would recover from in the event of a "disaster".

Can a single node Elasticsearch server be thought of to be as reliable as say a single node MySQL DB (pretty reliable in the grand scheme)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theoretical terms, reliability [can defined as](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reliability_engineering) as the probability of success, in other terms as `1-probability of failure`.

It is common knowledge that [no systems operate with 100% reliability](http://techblog.netflix.com/2014/09/introducing-chaos-engineering.html) and even more so with a single point of failure (=single node), i.e. the probability of failure can thus never be 0, even for Amazon monsters. So, according to the absolute theory, a single node is **not reliable**.

That being said, in the end the notion of reliability is always relative (as opposed to the absolute sense defined above), which means that it is finally up to you to decide what you deem reliable or not, i.e. you don't care if your node goes down once a day/week/month during 3 minutes and still reaches 99.999% uptime.

Another very concrete issue is that you need to figure out if a single node can hold 100MM documents and still serve search requests, aggregations and what have you, fast enough and still be beneficial for your users.

The first limit to be attained is usually the amount of heap, which is not [supposed to be higher than 30.5GB](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/heap-sizing.html). Roughly said, you need to figure out if your 100MM docs will hold in such a single node with 30.5 GB of heap. It's trivial to test: provision your ES service, load it up with all your documents and run some load testing mimicking the expected load of your users, you'll quickly find out if you run out of memory or not and the answer to this question will be straightforward in the end.

Comment: In my experience it is essential to use `doc_values` if Java heap space is constrained (and maybe even if it isn't), at one instance by mistake I wasn't using them and query times jumped from 10 ms to 3 seconds as field-data cache had to be trashed and re-built constantly.

Comment: Definitely agree. It definitely makes sense, though in this case, @Kong wants to use a single node with 100MM docs, so at some point even with doc_values and what have you, a single node might be too constrained... or not. But the only way to find out is to test it out.